# Formatting sql datetime to MM/dd/yyyy using C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date stored in SQL. When I get the value back I want to format as `MM/dd/yyyy`, but I'm getting values like `2020-09-01` instead.

```
AccountHolderRenewalDate = a.AccountRenewalDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Both `AccountHolderRenewalDate` and `a.AccountRenewalDate` are strings. `a.AccountRenewalDate` holds the date I'm after.

What would I be doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the (c#) datatype of `AccountRenewalDate`? `DateTime`?

Comment: @gunr2171, its a string in my data class  public string AccountRenewalDate

Comment: You can't use `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` on a string, only a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Parse it into a DateTime first, then ToString it into the desired format.

Comment: And why do you use a string to represent a datetime? This is a well know source of problems

Comment: @steve, inherited code

Comment: @Steve sometimes that's reasonable.  I have a third-party system here that stores dates in a log as a varchar field.  It's convenient to work with that as a string in C#, since we don't do transformations on the date.  However, OP should definitely not call it a date if its a string.

Comment: If `AccountRenewalDate` really was a string, your code would not compile. There is no overload of `ToString` for a string that accepts a string as an argument.

Comment: @gunr2171, you must be talking about the a.AccountRenewableDate, thats from the linq query

Comment: @Amy What naming convention should be used that both indicate the content (date) and type (string)?

Comment: I made an edit to alleviate any confusion

Comment: I rolled back that edit because the code added was not relevant and added noise to the post. The more important code that has not been added would be the models.

Comment: @gunr2171, i added it because you seemed confused in one of your comments, "If AccountRenewalDate really was a string, your code would not compile"

Comment: @gunr2171, I know I can change the AccountRenewableDate from a string to a datetime in the model, but if I do I am not sure of the repercussions, down the line with the rest of the code or any other methods that use the AccountHolderList model

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick - I'm assuming that your DB is a Date column so I didn't use DateTime.TryParse:

```
DateTime.Parse(AccountHolderRenewalDate).ToString("d");
```

If you want 09/01 instead of 9/1 use

```
.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

instead